# android, moving from icu4j to icu4c

Tags: android, icu

i have class used with android frameworks, it calls icu4j's Arabicshaping. now i'v merged this class with another android branch that uses icu4c ( c implementation). but build process gives me error saying cannot find Arabicshaping...

searching in icu4c files shows me that it has both ArabicShaping.c and ushape.c

but i don't know how to call them from framewoks java code .

any idea?  thanks